# Make a Mac .App run a script on running of said .App

Tags: python, macos, shell, .app

I have a script (Shell, chmod-ed to 755. Python is in the script, meaning not run from an outside .py file) that is executable. It works when I run it. How can I make a .app that executes said script on runtime? I have a simple .app that has this structure: `APPNAME.App>Contents>MacOS>script`
This does not run. Is there any way I can piggyback a script onto another application, The Powder Toy, for example? I'm not new to OSX, I just don't have root privileges and can't install XCode. 
Rembember, I can't install anything from source or use setup scripts, effectively annihilating py2app as an option.
EDIT:
This answer is courtesy of mklement0. Automator lets you choose the environment to run your script, type it in, and bundle it into a .app, removing the need for a shell script.

Comment: Again, this needs to be run on others' computers with only the click of a mouse. I know how to make that, as I've made one before. I can NOT use Automator or AppleScript. I need to have the script run on startup of a .app.

Comment: Automator can create `*.app` files that wrap shell scripts. Why is that not an option?

Comment: Hmmm... Let me check. I tried with applescript a moment ago, to no avail.

Comment: Thanks, mklement0. I chose the environment /usr/bin/python and copied my script in. Perfect. :) Also, how do I mark the question as "Answered"?

Comment: Glad to hear it. To accept an answer, click the large check mark next to it. If no existing answer satisfies you, you can write your own answer and accept it, but only after 48 hours.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer and check the "help" link in the footer for more guidance.

Comment: I was under the assumption that I could simply declare a question "Answered". I can see why that rule is in place. It would be bad to have tons of abandoned questions claiming to have been answered when, in reality, no answer was there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Run `Automator` and create a new `Application` project.
- Add a `Run Shell Script` action.
- In the `Shell:` list, select the interpreter of choice; `/usr/bin/python` in this case.
- Paste the *contents* of your Python script into the action and save the `*.app` bundle.

Comment: Thanks. I can't answer my own questions yet. I know what stackoverflow's goal is, but this is a very strict ruleset.

Comment: You're welcome; you _can_ answer your own question, but while you have fewer than 100 reputation points, you'll have to wait 8 hours after posting the question - see http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: "I can't answer my own questions `yet`."

Comment: @mckryall Got it; I missed that nuance; I thought you were talking about a _reputation_ threshold.

Answer (score 0):

if your using applescript, just save it as a bundle by save as, and click the drop down saying script, change that to bundle i think. after that, click on the bundle icon in apple script and drag the script to the folder you want. to run it put your run command in and drag the script that you placed in the bundle folders before in the directory slot of the run command. i can not give you anything exact due to the fact that i am not on my mac, but i am giving you the best i know.

Comment: No, I'm using shell. I intend to have this run on computers other that my own, serving people who don't even know what the terminal _is_. I need details on manually making a .app.

Comment: oh, here take a look at this. http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/shell-script-mac-apps. it looks simple enough :)